# How to Evaluate this integral in the simplest way?

Tags: calculus

Find $$\int 5^{(x^2)}\; dx.$$

Show me the step to find this please!

Comment: Note that the derivative of u^x is (u^x)log(u). Does this help?

Comment: @Upside- I am bad with calculus, please help

Comment: Victor: Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: @Thomas - I make it up by my own and had tried it as hard as possible?

Comment: The problem is that the integral is like $\int e^{x^2}\;dx$ and we can't write this down. This doesn't mean that there isn't an antiderivative, just that we can't write it down with the usual functions available.

Comment: Note that we don't compute primitives, but rather find them. We compute definite integrals, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See about [Dawson's integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2).  Keep in mind that $5=e^{\ln{5}}$.

Comment: Congratulations on the $1000$ answers!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\exp(x^2\log 5)=5^{x^2}$$

You're looking at something of the form $$\int e^{\alpha x^2}dx$$

which is the same as finding a primitive for  $$\int e^{  x^2}dx$$

after a change of variables. But this has not a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions, so your original integral has not one either. You can use that if $$G(x)=\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt$$ then $G'(x)=\exp x^2$ to find approximations using Taylor expansions.